# Decimal position changes from before number to after number when calculating numbers

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

So I'll explain this as best I can.
I'm just making a calculator for fun to help learn more about VB.
I have a Label whose property I have set to RightToLeft = Yes. 
So when I enter a number in the TextBox = .3567 and then click add,subtract,etc... it sends the previously entered value (of .3567) to my label. But when it does that, The number changes from ".3567" to "3567."

So I'm pretty sure the issue is in the RightToLeft property. Is there a way I can change this without removing the RightToLeft property?

**Edit:**
I've tried doing some things programmatically, like trying to find the substring of the decimal and removing it and then placing it at the beginning. but nothing happens when I try that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you wrote

> Is there a way I can change this without removing the RightToLeft property?

and there sure might be some way.

However, `RightToLeft` is for writing or displaying languages that are written from right to left, e.g. Arabic, not for entering or displaying numbers. Use the `TextAlign` property instead.

Comment: Duh... I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!